# In the context 2 Cor. 12:1-10, what is the sufficient grace (v 9) the Lord refers to and what the sufficient mean?

Tags: pauline-epistles

Text: 2 Cor. 12:1-10 (ESV)

> I must go on boasting. Though there is nothing to be gained by it, I
> will go on to visions and revelations of the Lord. I know a man in
> Christ who fourteen years ago was caught up to the third
> heaven—whether in the body or out of the body I do not know, God
> knows. And I know that this man was caught up into paradise—whether in
> the body or out of the body I do not know, God knows— and he heard
> things that cannot be told, which man may not utter. On behalf of this
> man I will boast, but on my own behalf I will not boast, except of my
> weaknesses— though if I should wish to boast, I would not be a fool,
> for I would be speaking the truth; but I refrain from it, so that no
> one may think more of me than he sees in me or hears from me. So to
> keep me from becoming conceited because of the surpassing greatness of
> the revelations, a thorn was given me in the flesh, a messenger of
> Satan to harass me, to keep me from becoming conceited. 8Three times I
> pleaded with the Lord about this, that it should leave me. But he said
> to me, “My grace is sufficient for you, for my power is made perfect
> in weakness.” Therefore I will boast all the more gladly of my
> weaknesses, so that the power of Christ may rest upon me. 10For the
> sake of Christ, then, I am content with weaknesses, insults,
> hardships, persecutions, and calamities. For when I am weak, then I am
> strong.

Answer (score 1):

While there are many related questions on this list (search "my grace is sufficient"), none address the meaning of ἀρκέω in this context.

**Figure 1.** Senses of ἀρκέω in the New Testament (generated with Logos Bible Software)

[image: ![enter image description here]

Here, while *sufficient* covers the idea, there is also the connotation of *to be content, satisfied*.  While it would be helpful if we knew that the "thorn in the flesh" was.  This question has been debated for two millennia with no definite answer, whether physical or spiritual illness, or even a person.  Multiple questions or on the list related to this (search "thorn in the flesh")

Some of Paul's statements related to this idea are:

> Not that I am speaking of being in need, for I have learned in whatever situation I am to be content [αὐτάρκης].
> (Phil. 4:11, ESV)

> And we know that for those who love God all things work together for good, for those who are called according to his purpose.
> (Rom. 8:28, ESV)

> giving thanks always and for everything to God the Father in the name of our Lord Jesus Christ, 21 submitting to one another out of reverence for Christ.
> (Eph. 5:20–21, ESV)

Paul not only wrote these words.  He lived them.

**P.S:** Many times we have questions about Scripture that we aren't given an answer. Sometimes we need to ask, "Why?" Specifically why do we not know what Pauls thorn in the flesh was?  If we knew, then we would apply the passage to Paul's particular thorn, but maybe God's intent was for Paul's statements to be generalized for us to apply to our own particular thorns in the flesh.

That God did not take it away lead Paul to learn what he stated in the above statements.  God's grace is sufficient in giving us the gifts we need to fulfill His purpose in our lives, and often what He doesn't give also fulfills that purpose.